# Fantasy set in ancient China

Tags: story-identification

I read a book when I was a teenager set in ancient China.  There was magic and I believe a phoenix was involved.  The story involved some kind of quest, and travelling through some caves underground.  There was an old wise man / wizard type character.  The cover had some big limestone dome hills on it.  Anybody know what it was?

Comment: Magic, phoenixes, quests, underground caves and old wise men/wizard types are pretty standard features of a lot of fantasy books. Can you remember anything else about the book? Character names, the name of the author, part of the title, etc would be useful. Also, a rough idea of when you read it and whether it was new at the time could be helpful.

Comment: Phoenices, maybe?

Comment: *Journey Into The West*? Seems like it has a few of the mentioned elements.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you be referring to [Barry Hughart's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barry_Hughart) series of fantasy novels featuring Master Li and Number Ten Ox? I read them many years ago, so I don't remember many particulars, but the setting fits, and Master Li fits the "wise old man" trope. I couldn't find any phoenixes in the Wikipedia overviews, though.

The cover of the first book, [*Bridge of Birds*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_of_Birds), seems to be hilly.

Comment: It's actually the Story of the Stone by Hughart: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Story_of_the_Stone_(Barry_Hughart)

Comment: However, no magic or Phoenix apparently.. the deficiencies of memory..  I guess this may mean it's not Fantasy, only Adventure, and doesn't belong on this site?

Comment: Wikipedia describes its setting as "a fantastical version of imperial China", and the plot might not be full of classic high fantasy tropes, but it does have many legendary tropes such as people back from the dead, descent into hell, and such. I call "on topic".

Comment: It's def on topic, and a great read besides.

Comment: It is unquestionably fantasy, but set place in mythical China instead of mythical Europe. And it has everything from magic to zombies, immortal villains, monsters, etc. it is a fantastic trilogy but the first is my fav.